# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

Full error:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/tutorials' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

On the frontend I am using NuxtJS. I am sending a simple post request at the node server hosted on localhost:3000, but it's giving me this error even though I am using CORS in my app. The request is for inserting data in the mongodb database.

On the node server i.e. localhost:8080, I've tried:

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Tried this too but no success:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  next();
});
```

Please tell if there is any solution for this error. Thank you.

EDITED:

Here, I am using axios to first create an instance (on the frontend).
https://ibb.co/C2ChH5d

These are all the requests that I want to use.
https://ibb.co/5TbSHjF

And this is the request that is being made currently(create).
https://ibb.co/pPp8rdh

The nodeJS code: https://ibb.co/GFWMQW1

NodeJS code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

require("./app/routes/tutorial.routes")(app);

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
};

app.options("*", cors());

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to bezkoder application." });
});

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

const db = require("./app/models");
db.mongoose
  .connect(db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
    process.exit();
  });
```

Comment: those two attempts at fixing your issue - which server did you set that on? 8080 or 3000?

Comment: On node server i.e. 8080 because the resources are being accessed from that. 
When I am sending requests through postman, it's not giving this error.

Comment: yeah, postman isn't limited by CORS - so, the code loaded using :3000 makes the api request on :8080 and it's :8080 that has the use(cors) ... can you show the code that makes the request

Comment: The error message says **preflight** this is covered in the manual for the module you are using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: @Quentin I am a newbie in nodejs. Please tell which code i've to use. I've tried this one 'app.options('*', cors())' but still giving the same error

Comment: @Bravo I've attached some images above please check. It's still giving the same error.

Comment: I see the problem - your code seems to be a bunch of pictures rather than text - in other words, don't post pictures of code, post code

Comment: @Bravo The code is divided into many components and different files. But since the request is sending from postman means there is no problem with rest of the code. Only the nodejs code (where the cors part is present) is relevant to this problem. I've posted the nodeJS code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was that I was using the API routes before initializing `cors()`. When I shifted the routes down the `app.use(cors(corsOptions))`, the problem was solved.